# Lie-algebra-valued one-forms evaluated at a specific point

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, differential-forms, principal-bundles

If we have a Lie-algebra-valued one-form $\omega:\Gamma(TP)\longrightarrow T_eG$ where $(P,\pi,M)$ is a principal $G$-bundle, how is the map "$\omega_p$", produced by evaluating the one form at a particular point $p\in P$ defined? If we evaluate a vector field at a point we get a vector, so my guess is something like $$\omega_p:T_pP\longrightarrow ???,$$ but I'm not sure what it would mean to "evaluate an element of the Lie algebra at a point", so I can't extend my guess to the target of the map. The reason I ask is because at around the 12 minute mark in this lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhagmmNvOvQ from Frederic Schuller's "Lectures on the Geometric Anatomy of Theoretical Physics", he defines the Yang-Mills field $\omega^U:=\sigma^*\omega$ (with $\sigma$ a section of the principal bundle) as taking a *vector field* to an element of the Lie Algebra, but then at 22:50 of that same lecture he plugs a *vector* into $\omega^U$, writing $\omega^U(v)$ with $v\in T_mU$ (where $U$ is a chart domain of $M$).

I have a number of closely related confusions that I think pretty much boil down to this one, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Example: The usual kind of one-forms you know are also Lie-algebra valued one-forms, they are valued in the abelian Lie-algebra $\Bbb R$. More generally if $\omega$ is to be valued in the Lie-algebra $\mathfrak g$ then at every point $p\in P$ you have that $\omega_p: T_pP\to\mathfrak g$ is linear.

Comment: So even after evaluating the one form at $p\in P$, the target of $\omega_p$ is still the Lie algebra? I've been thinking the target might be the group $G$, in the following lecture he uses a construction where $G$ is a matrix group, and some $\omega_p(X)$ ($X$ a vector) is matrix-multiplied by an element of $G$ (28:47 here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGHaZc2fuX8)

Comment: If $X$ is a vector then $\omega_p(X)$ is an element of the Lie-algebra. If $g(\lambda)$ is an element of the Lie group then conjugating $\omega_p(X)$ by $g(\lambda)$ is well defined, this is called the adjoint action of the Lie group on the Lie algebra. For matrix groups the adjoint action can be described by matrix multiplication: $\mathrm{Ad}_{g(\lambda)}(\omega_p(X)) = g(\lambda)^{-1} \omega_p(X) g(\lambda)$.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I thought Ad was a map from $G\times G \longrightarrow G$ and ad was a map from $T_eG \longrightarrow T_eG$, it wasn't clear to me that we can define a map $Ad:G\times T_eG \longrightarrow T_eG$. What if $G$ is not a matrix Lie group? How do we interpret the "product" $g(\lambda)^{-1}\omega_p(X)g(\lambda)$?

Comment: There are three different adjoint maps. I think the usual notation is $\mathrm{AD}$, $\mathrm{Ad}$ and $\mathrm{ad}$. As you can tell by the capitalisation they differ in how much group $G$ or algebra $\mathfrak g$ there is involved. $\mathrm{AD}: G\to \mathrm{Hom}(G,G)$ is given by $g\mapsto \mathrm{AD}_g= [h\mapsto g^{-1}hg]$. $\mathrm{Ad}: G\to \mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak g), g\mapsto \mathrm{Ad}_g$ is given by the derivative of $\mathrm{AD}_g(h)$ by $h$ at 1, $\mathrm{Ad}_g(w)=D_1\mathrm{AD}_g\,[w]$. Finally $\mathrm{ad}_w$ is given by the derivative of $\mathrm{Ad}_g$ by $g$ at $1$.

Comment: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) for a more thorough defintion of these maps